# Comments in plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, plist

I want to save all apis to a plist file. Absolutely It's a key-value pair. The key is a number like 1001, and the value is the api path string. What I need is to add a comment for per api pair for other developers feeling easy to read it. I know the `<!-- comments -->` style comment can be done in the plist source files, but you know I want to make the comments appear in the plist file(not in file source code) what's looks like opening in Xcode. See:

[image]

Is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as any code that reads the XML (like `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]`) will discard the `<!-- ... -->` comments.

The only way to make them persist is to make the comments part of the data being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Create the API Object as **dictionary** and add a comment object which can be read!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the structure of the plist file. for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>content</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>coment</key>
            <string>the things you want to say</string>
            <key>2001</key>
            <string>image/%@</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>the things you want to say</string>
            <key>1001</key>
            <string>image////</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>your comment</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

sorry,I can't upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can interactively add (and edit) a comment (use `Comment` or whatever you want as keyword) into an existing plist file with the help of Apple's `Property List Editor` stored under `/Developer/Applications/Utilities` or `/DevTools/Application//Utilities`.